# Does 彼女は私と一緒にいればよかった mean wish she WAS with me or wish she HAD been with me?

Tags: grammar, tense, conditionals

> 彼女は私と一緒にいればよかった

Does it mean

- *I wish she was with me (right now)*, or
- *I wish she had been with me (in the past)*?

Answer (score 3):

You might not believe this, but the sentence:

> 「彼女**は**私と一緒にいればよかった。」

means ***neither*** of the two things you listed.  Instead, it means something completely different.  It means:

> "She was happy/good if she was with me."

In other words, it means:

> "All she asked was to be with me."

If your sentence had used 「彼女**が**」 instead of 「彼女**は**」, I would have answered this question in a totally different way.  I, however, should not be answering a question you did not ask, so I will stop here.

Comment: Ah, forgive me, its a common beginners mistake! So, if it was 「彼女が私と一緒にいればよかった。」?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on context whether the た of wishes is present or past. So we can't determine which your sentence is.

For example:

> *この*景色を彼女と一緒に見られれば**よかった**。
>
> I wish I could see this scenery with her (*now*).

---

> *あの時*彼女と一緒にいられれば**よかった**。
>
> I wish I could have been with her *at that time*.